# Calculate offset().top on reload always as if viewport is scrolled to top

Tags: jquery, html

I'm using offset()top to calculate the position of a header in relation of the viewport, and then applying a class to that header when it is scolled up to the viewport top.

All is working fine. The problem is when the page is reloaded scrolled down, in which case the offset is calculated from this point, and the effects on the div only triggers from there down.

Is there a way to make offset().top calculate this initial point always as if the viewport were scrolled to top?

Here is the js,

```
     jQuery(function(){

        var menuTopo = jQuery('#titulo').offset().top;

          jQuery(window).scroll(function(){
                if( jQuery(window).scrollTop() > menuTopo ) {
                        jQuery('#titulo').removeClass("gde").addClass("peq");
                } else {
                            jQuery('#titulo').removeClass("peq").addClass("gde");
                } 
          });
      });
```

and here is html.

```
    <body id="body">

    <div id="titulo" class="gde">wederãlab</div>

    (sidebar, content)...

   </body>
```

Comment: Why not add a  JQuery(document).ready(function(){ check scrollTop} instead of having it activated only on scroll?
 
Does this solve the problem?

Comment: How would I implement that exactly, @HristoGeorgiev?

Comment: I posted an answer. Let me know if it works for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understood your question, you just need to run the same function, but when the document has finished loading:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
      testHeader();


    $(window).scroll(function () {

        testHeader();
    });



});


function testHeader() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 0) {
        $('#titulo').removeClass("gde").addClass("peq");

    } else {
        $('#titulo').removeClass("peq").addClass("gde");
    }

}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RpPEe/3076/)

This should work in both cases - when the page is loaded and when you scroll.

Comment: I didn't worked. It broke the function completely, in fact. 

Maybe I'm not being clear. If you prefer, go to the website and reproduce the error like this:

  1) go to www.arvoreamarela.art.br/wederalab
  2) scroll down to see the normal function (side menu slides to left, header get smaller)
  3) with the viewport anywhere but the top, reload the page.
  4) scroll up and down again to see how the header and side menu effects acting strange (as if the top was the point were the page was at reload).

Maybe this helps to understand better the problem.

Comment: I added a JSFiddle and refactored the code. Let me know if this works.